# Trying to edit a comment to contain forbidden content makes weird things happen

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-edits

I'd just posted a comment that read:

> Huh? `json.dumps` converts the dict back to a (JSON-encoded) string. That's not what the OP wanted to do.

I tried to edit it to read:

> -1; huh? `json.dumps` converts the dict back to a (JSON-encoded) string. That's not what the OP wanted to do.

and got the red popup saying:

> Comments cannot contain that content.
>
> Don't comment on your downvote. If you think this post can be *improved*, please offer **specific guidance**. See: [The Comment Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Okay, whatever. But then I clicked "cancel" on my comment edit (without dismissing the red box), then clicked "edit" again (before the moment at which the red box would otherwise have faded away), and suddenly the red error box was *blocking* the comment box.

Upon dismissing the red box, suddenly I had this nonsense written in the text field beneath:

> Huh? `json.dumps` converts the dict back to a (JSON-encoded) string. That's not what the OP wanted to do. -1.×Comments cannot contain that content.Don't comment on your downvote. If you think this post can be improved, please offer specific guidance. See: The Comment Privilege.×Comments cannot contain that content.Don't comment on your downvote. If you think this post can be improved, please offer specific guidance. See: The Comment Privilege.×Comments cannot contain that content.Don't comment on your downvote. If you think this post can be improved, please offer specific guidance. See: The Comment Privilege.

I can reproduce this on other comments. Seems to be a very odd bug.

Here's a gif showing the WTFery in action. For the avoidance of any doubt, I don't paste anything here and the only keypresses I perform are typing "test test test test", pressing Enter to initially submit the comment, and typing "-1 ".

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Nope @MarkAmery Can't reproduce. Tried both on my own post and other posts. Can you [edit] and delineate the steps again?

Comment: @BhargavRao I've added a gif. Works for me in Chrome on Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: I can confirm this is happening on Windows 10 pro x64 Chrome Version 47.0.2526.111 m

Comment: +3/-3 for a perfectly legitimate bug report. We're assuming *way* too much, guys.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi a slightly poor show from the downvoters, but it's a sufficiently bizarre bug that it's not that surprising that many of the initial viewers misunderstood WTF I was trying to describe. The gif should ward off further confusion (besides the confusion I'm experiencing about how the heck a bug like this could happen in the first place).

Comment: Ok, perfect. Reproduced on Chrome Ubu 15.04

Comment: [Similar bug on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272912/comments-may-only-be-edited-for-5-minutes-appears-in-comment).

Comment: The horrible bug also still exists where your comment will be automatically deleted when it contains the word "duplicate" and a link to a duplicate question when the question you commented on is closed as a duplicate of the one that comment links to. It wasn't supposed to happen if the comment was edited, but last week I still saw it in effect. Is that what SE means by _"comments are second-class citizens"_?

Comment: Ooh. Yummy. Bugs. And Downvotes? Sounds like a feast :P

Comment: @CodeCaster that sounds very funky. And yes, I guess all bets are off with comments ('cause, you know, [we need them pearlz](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), not chit-chat;)

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome with the 5 second comment edit error I got this when I edited again: `test test test test×You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.×You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.×You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.`

Comment: Reproduced across the SE network on Chrome v45.

Comment: Seems to be a(nother) Chrome bug

Comment: How I *wish* all testers report bugs like this :)

Comment: @TylerH also reproduced on Firefox 43.0.4

Comment: Very very nice bugreport. Nicest one i've ever seen. IF customers  did it that way the world would be such a beautiful place.

Comment: It seems it isn't reproducible on MSO

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ yup, meta sites doesn't have such check.

Comment: How would the code for a tooltip even be able to make this happen accidentally? I'm legit curious.

Comment: Apparently some people need to do less building SO and more using it.

Comment: What program did you use to create/record the gif? Going to send it to our QA...

Comment: @BradThomas That's true for most software.  Actually I take that back, that's true for *most consumer products.*

Comment: I will link this to instruct people I work with on how to file a good bug report. Nice work @Mark Amery. I had this happen once myself, but I'm an horrible monster and didn't report it.

Comment: @MarkC.it's called [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/). I don't think there a version for any platform besides Windows, and it's the first time I've ever used it so I can't vouch for it, but it seems pretty nifty.

Comment: @MarkAmery Thanks! I appreciate it. Sent to our QA haha

Comment: @MarkC. for Linux you have ffmpeg package.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Presumably the html for the popup is nested inside the text box and isn't removed when you click cancel.

Answer (score 10):

Fix rolling out soon, see [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275828/156631) for details.